# prediction of two variables using multivariate linear regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, linear

I'm trying to predict two features which are correlated to each other and also correlated to 4 other features that are given. how can i do this estimation using that 4 given features in matlab?

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV. In order to give a helpful answer, some more information is needed. What are the circumstances under which this regression should work, are the values continuous, etc. Maybe you can add also some histograms from the input and target values, possible with scatter plots.

Comment: actually the whole data is about some features of the movies that are considered in scoring them. so i assume the features are continuous.and in previous part we created the covariane coefficient matrix of the features using corrcoef. now we want to estimate the best value for a numerical feature, observing the 4 other given ones

Comment: ACK. But the current question is still "how to do x in Matlab?", which is not the purpose of this SE site. Even considering Matlab, it is still unclear what your inputs are (continuous, discrete, categorical, ...), as well as the outputs. Do want to de-correlate the output? etc.